# Show that $\lambda$ is a repeated root of $p(z)$ if and only if $p(\lambda) = p'(\lambda) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> Suppose $p \in \mathcal{P}\mathbb{(C)}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Applying the division algorithm, we know there exists $q \in \mathcal{P}\mathbb{(C)}$ and $r \in \mathbb{C}$ such that 
>   $$p(z) = q(z)(z-\lambda) + r$$
>   Show that $p'(\lambda) = q(\lambda)$ and use this to deduce that $\lambda$ is a repeated root of $p(z)$ if and only if $p(\lambda) = p'(\lambda) = 0$.  (Note: - A repeated root of $p$ is a root that appears at least twice in the complete factorization of $p$, which is equivalent to $(z - \lambda)^2$ is a factor of p.)

To show that $p'(\lambda) = q(\lambda)$, if I take the derivative of $p(z)$, I get $$ p'(z) = q'(z)(z-\lambda) + q(z)$$

Then plugging in $z = \lambda$, $$ p'(\lambda) = q'(\lambda)(\lambda-\lambda) + q(\lambda)$$
and $p'(\lambda) = q(\lambda)$ appears as desired.

$\rightarrow$ this direction I think is straight forward. Suppose that $\lambda$ is a repeated root of $p(z)$. Then p and p' can be represented as 
$$p(z) = (\lambda - \lambda)^2f(z)$$
$$p'(z) = 2(z-\lambda)f(z) + (z-\lambda)^2 f(z)$$

(per 4.11 theorem from textbook). Plugging in $z = \lambda$,

$$p(\lambda) = (\lambda - \lambda)^2f(\lambda) = 0$$
$$p'(\lambda) = 2(\lambda-\lambda)f(\lambda) + (\lambda-\lambda)^2 f(\lambda) = 0$$

Thus $p(\lambda) = p'(\lambda) = 0$.

$\leftarrow$ **this side is really messing me up**. I start with supposing $p(\lambda) = p'(\lambda) = 0$. Considering the original $p(z) = q(z)(z-\lambda) + r$ I want to show that $p(\lambda) = p'(\lambda) = 0$ using the fact that $q(\lambda) = p'(\lambda)$, but not sure how to start this. Any help or ideas in the right direction would be appreciated. I feel like I keep going in circles looking at $p(z)$ and $p'(z)$ trying to find something when there is nothing more left to find.

[image]

Comment: Do a proof by contradiction. $p(\lambda)=0$ means that $\lambda$ is a zero of $p$, but suppose it was not a repeated root. This means $p$ would have to be of the form $(z-\lambda)q(z)$ where $q$ does not have a $0$ at $\lambda$. What happens with the derivative?

Comment: The polynomial $q(z)=p(z)-p(\lambda)-p'(\lambda)(z-\lambda)$ in $z$ that has $\lambda$ as a double root. It is clear that it vanishes at $z=\lambda$. If you divide by $z-\lambda$, the quotient also vanishes at $z=\lambda$. If $p(\lambda)=p'(\lambda)=0$, then $q(z)=p(z)$. So, $p(z)$ also has $\lambda$ as a double root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$p(\lambda)=0\tag 1.$$

You already proved that $p'(\lambda)=q(\lambda)$ which implies $$q(\lambda)=p'(\lambda)=0\tag2.$$

For $(2)$  take $q(z)=(z-\lambda)t(z)$ where $t(\lambda)\ne 0$. On plugging this in

$p(z)=(z-\lambda)q(z)+r$

You get $p(z)=(z-\lambda)^2t(z)+r$. Now use $(1)$ to get $r=0$ and then $p(z)=(z-\lambda)^2q(z)$ shows the result.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lambda$ is a repeated root of $p(z)$, then

$p(z) = (x - \lambda)^2q(z), \tag 1$

from which, *via* differentiation,

$p'(z) = 2(z - \lambda)q(z) + (z - \lambda)^2q'(z); \tag 2$

from (1),

$p(\lambda) = (\lambda - \lambda)^2q(\lambda) = 0, \tag 3$

whilst from (2),

$p'(\lambda) = 2(\lambda - \lambda)q(\lambda) + (\lambda - \lambda)^2 q'(\lambda) = 0 \tag 4$

as well, which shows that $\lambda$ is a multiple root of $p(z)$ implies

$p(\lambda) = p'(\lambda) = 0. \tag 5$

***Going the other way:***

Suppose now we are given that (5) binds; in accord with the division algorithm for polynomials we may write

$p(z) = (z - \lambda)q(z) + r, \tag 6$

where

$0 \le \deg r < \deg (z - \lambda) = 1; \tag 7$

it follows then that

$\deg r = 0 \Longrightarrow r \in \Bbb C, \tag 8$

and taking $z = \lambda$ in (6) we find

$0 = p(\lambda) = (\lambda - \lambda)q(\lambda) + r = r; \tag 9$

with $r = 0$, (6) becomes

$p(z) = (z - \lambda)q(z), \tag {10}$

whence, upon taking derivatives,

$p'(z) = q(z) + (x - \lambda)q'(z); \tag{11}$

again with $z = \lambda$,

$0 = p'(\lambda) = q(\lambda); \tag{12}$

with $q(\lambda) = 0$ we may essentially repeat the argument of (6)-(10) to infer the existence of some

$s(z) \in \Bbb C[z] \tag{13}$

with

$q(z) = (z - \lambda)s(z), \tag{14}$

and returning to (10) we find

$p(z) = (z - \lambda)q(z) = (z - \lambda)^2 s(z), \tag{15}$

so $\lambda$ is a multiple root of $p(z)$.

[Show that $\lambda$ is a repeated root of $p(z)$ if and only if $p(\lambda) = p'(\lambda) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399639/show-that-lambda-is-a-repeated-root-of-pz-if-and-only-if-p-lambda-p)